# What causes a "Community Event Buff"?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just logged in to play, and was greeted with a Community Event Buff (Your Experience gain is increased by 50%):

[image: Screenshot showing Community Event Buff tooltip]

What causes this? I'm only part of one community, which I created and promptly forgot existed. What are "Community Events"? How do they work?

Comment: I also have this buff, and I'm not in any community whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The buff has nothing to do with in game community or groups as it sounds,and also it is not repeatable event...or at least until next expansion.

This particular buff is given to all players who log in diablo 3 between **03/03/14 to 24/03/14**(Reaper of souls release date) from PC of Mac.

This is part of the **promotion of RotS and new 2.0.1. patch**.
Blizzard basically wants to get as much people as they can back to the game before RotS releases,just to show them what they changed and to get them excited increasing the chances of them buying the expansion.

[Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/12891934/) is the official blizzard article,and [here](http://www.blizzposts.com/blogentry/en/123708/50-bonus-xp-in-diablo-iii-limited-time-only) is the copy of the same article if you have trouble viewing it.

Comment: Just when I thought I was out...

Comment: @Sterno btw the bonus is 100% for this weekend now